# Microsoft Graph - ASP.NET Core - Insufficient privileges

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, adal

I have a working ASP.NET Core multi-tenant ADAL webapp. I'm working on integrating Microsoft Graph, but when I try to use a method on `Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient` (eg. `var me = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();`), I get the error below:

> Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

I'm able to get correctly the Access Token. If I copy-paste the token from runtime to Postman, it is working correctly:

[image: postman screenshot]

But for the same token, it throws an error in ASP.NET core.

Comment: Are you sure the access token is being passed to the request?  Can you use a tool like Fiddler to look at the network request and confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that I was requesting a token for the second time (badly) after the first successful token instead of just reading it out from TokenCache.

### The solution:

Getting token from authorization code **at login** and storing it in cache:

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(string userId, string code)
{
    TokenCache userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(userId, _memoryCache).GetCacheInstance();

    try
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_aadInstance, userTokenCache);
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(_appId, _appSecret);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(_redirectUri), credential, _graphResourceId);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And when requesting a `GraphServiceClient` I just read the correct token from cache:

```
public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync(string userId)
{
    TokenCache userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(userId, _memoryCache).GetCacheInstance();

    try
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_aadInstance, userTokenCache);
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(_appId, _appSecret);
        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_graphResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

        return result.AccessToken;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```